# Strange behavior with the ACE Editor's UndoManager

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Using the [ACE Editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about), it appears as if using `editor.getSession().getUndoManager()` with a session that has been set with `editor.setSession()` returns an `UndoManager` object that contains only empty functions for `undo()`, `redo()`, and `reset()`. It does not return an UndoManager with methods like `hasUndo()`, or `hasRedo()`, or any of the other [documented methods](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=undomanager). In the source, it looks like my the session must not have an `$undoManager` and is forced to use an empty (and incomplete) `$defaultUndoManager`:

```
this.$defaultUndoManager = {
    undo: function() {},
    redo: function() {},
    reset: function() {}
};

this.getUndoManager = function() {
    return this.$undoManager || this.$defaultUndoManager;
};
```

Why would a session that was set with editor.setSession() have an `$undoManager` that is `undefined` like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like one is supposed to set undo manager on the session like [this (ace.js#L112)](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.4/lib/ace/ace.js#L112)
And if undomamager is missing defaultUndomanager is returned so that editor methods do not have to check for null, when accessing undomanager.
I think the reason EditSession doesn't create undoManager by itself is to allow users to provide special implementations of undomanager (e.g. for collaboration)

Comment: Fantastic! I was using `new ace.EditSession(...)` instead of `ace.createEditSession(...)`. Using `ace.createEditSession(...)` allowed me instant access to the appropriate undoManager.